# How can I add a label to each createTableViewRow and center everything?

Tags: javascript, android, css, titanium, titanium-mobile

Im populating each Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow from a json file, and I wonder how I can add a label (Titanium.UI.createLabel) to each created Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow and center all outputed text?
I have created a Titanium.UI.createLabel, but how to add my Label to each created Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow, and center all text?

This is a created Label:

```
var wrapperLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Signed:',
    color: '#ffffff',
    textAlign:'center',
    font: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 22
    },
    height:'auto'
});
win3.add(wrapperLabel);

var view = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    maxRowHeight:40,
    minRowHeight:30,
    height: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    color: 'black'
});
win3.add(view);

xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = [];
    var objects = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    for (s in objects) {
        data.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: objects[s]
        }));
        data.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: objects[s].New
        }));
        data.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: objects[s].Signed
        }));
        data.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: objects[s].Returned
        }));
    }
    view.data = data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for (s in objects) { 
     var label = Ti.UI.createLabel (_properties_);
     var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(_propeties_);
     row.add(label);
     data.push(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
var row_propetiy = {
     height : "40dp"
};

var lbl_propetiy = {
    color: '#000',
    textAlign:'center',
    font: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '22dp'
    },
    height:Ti.UI.FILL
};

xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = [];
    var objects = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    for (s in objects) {
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(row_propetiy);
        var lbl = Ti.UI.createLable(lbl_propetiy);
        lbl.text = objects[s];
        row.add(lbl);
        data.push(row);
    }
    view.data = data;
};
```